# No puedo llenar el formulario en movil

Tags: html, bootstrap

desarrolle un portal con bootstrap, pero en la sección contactos no me aparece el teclado del movil para llenarlo, es como que estuviera bloqueado.

Alguien me pueda ayudar, porque desde el navegador va normal, pero desde el movil no me deja.

```
http://svconstructions.com.ec/sv/contactos.php
```

Acá el codigo de la seccion

```
<section class="contact-form wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group  full-width">
                        <input type="text" name="" style="border:solid 1px #000" placeholder="Nombres">
                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    <div class="form-group  full-width">            
                        <input type="text" name="s" style="border:solid 1px #000" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    <div class="form-group full-width">
                        <input type="text" name="s" style="border:solid 1px #000" placeholder="Teléfono">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group full-width">              
                        <input type="text" name="" style="border:solid 1px #000" placeholder="Ciudad o Sector">
                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    <div class="form-group full-width">             
                        <input type="text" name="s" style="border:solid 1px #000" placeholder="Asunto">
                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    <div class="form-group full-width">            
                        <textarea name="s" style="border:solid 1px #000" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p> <a href="#" class="site-btn">Enviar</a></p>
                    </div><!-- end form-group -->
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 wow fadeInUp">
                <div class="title-box">
                    <!--  <h5>Moctezuma s/n y Caupolican</h5> -->
                    <h3>DATOS DE CONTACTO</h3>
                    <span></span> 
                </div><!-- end title-box -->
                    <address>

                        <p> <b>Dirección:</b> <br>Calle Moctezuma s/n y Avenida
                        Los Andes. <br> Sector Monay Shopping - Totoracocha <br><b>
                        Teléfono:</b><br> +593 7 828282<br><b>Correo Electrónico:</b> 
                        info@svconstructios.com.ec<br><br>Cuenca - Ecuador</p><br>

                    </address>
           </div><!-- end col-12 --> 
        </div><!-- end row --> 
    </div><!-- end container --> 
</section>
```

Comment: Tendrás que poner por lo menos el código del formulario para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya lo subi, estimado Luis

Comment: El enlace funciona correctamente en iPhone usando Safari y Chrome.

Comment: Si, yo lo solucioné, volví a crear el formulario y fruí probando uno por uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de escanear tu codigo a través de la pagina [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org) me arrojo varios errores en los input.

El primer input intenta quitarlo y de igual manera prueba quitando el de nombres y el de ciudad. Quizás eso sea el bloqueo del formulario en telefonos.

Comment: He corregido los errores del form, pero tampoco se desbloquean los campos.

Comment: Copie todo el codigo de la pagina completa y lo probe a traves de mi telefono y no me da ningun error. Claro, probando con tu pagina directamente no me da opción por el telefono.

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista puedo ver que tienes declarado el formulario pero no le dices por qué método vas a enviar los datos, o tendrás problemas luego para procesar los datos.

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Veo también que tienes el mismo **name** para distintos inputs, lo cual también puede traerte errores al procesar el formulario

Otra recomendación es que dejes el código más limpio, lo digo por los códigos css inline que tienes declarado en los mismos inputs, ponlo en un archivo css a parte, estará más aseado y tendrás más adelante un mejor mantenimiento.

El input que usas para el email, es de tipo texto, usa el tipo email, que es justo para ello

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
```

Respecto a que en el móvil se te bloque al formulario, yo he probado la dirección que has puesto y no me aparece bloqueado, por lo menos a mi.

Comment: Hola @Rodrypaladin, si lo que hice fue volver crear esta sección y el problema se ha solucionado.